# How to stop Black screen after Splash Screen?

Tags: android, progress-bar, splash-screen

I've used a splash screen and progress bar in my Android App.But after splash disappears,then next screen becomes black before switching to my main activity. But I don't want black screen.Can anyone please explain what's going on here and how can I prevent that black screen ? This is my Splash Java class.

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ProgressBar mProgress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.splash_screen_progress_bar);

        new Thread((new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doWork();
                startApp();
                finish();
            }
        }
        )).start();
    }

    private void doWork() {
        for (int progress = 0; progress < 100; progress += 10) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5500);
                mProgress.setProgress(progress);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void startApp() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly you want? Do you required next screen when progress finishes? or you want splash screen to show for few seconds and shift to next screen?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could remove the `finish()` inside the `Thread`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {
private ProgressBar mProgress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.splash_screen_progress_bar);

    new Thread((new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            doWork();
            startApp();

        }
    }
    )).start();
}

private void doWork() {
    for (int progress = 0; progress < 100; progress += 10) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5500);
            mProgress.setProgress(progress);
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void startApp() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

}

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. Thanks for improving the answer's reference value and making it more understandable!

Comment: the code was missing its return statement in dowork() method.

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1: 
If you required splash for few seconds:

```
new Thread((new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try { Thread.sleep(5500); }catch(Exception e) {}
            startApp();
            finish();
        }
    }
    )).start();
```

Approach 2: Show next screen when splash finish:

```
 public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ProgressBar mProgress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.splash_screen_progress_bar);

        new Thread((new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doWork();

            }
        }
        )).start();
    }

    private void doWork() {
        for (int progress = 0; progress < 100; progress += 10) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5500);
                mProgress.setProgress(progress);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        startApp();
        finish();
    }

    private void startApp() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one:**

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ProgressBar mProgress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.splash_screen_progress_bar);

        new Thread((new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doWork();
                }
        }
        )).start();
    }

    private void doWork() {
        for (int progress = 0; progress < 100; progress += 10) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5500);
                mProgress.setProgress(progress);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
          startApp();
    }

    private void startApp() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
     finish();
    }
}
```